# Rendering random array element from state (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to render a random array item from state so that (e.g - [0] might change to [2] on reload.]

Here is what I tried so far, any tips or ideas please?

here is my state:

```
     state = {
      randomItem: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
    },
    selected: null,
    clicked: false,
  };
```

here is my handleClick function which will randomise the items grabbed from array

```
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      clicked: true,
      selected: this.state.randomItem.selected[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.selected.length)
      ],
    });
  };
```

here is how im trying to return it

```
         <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleClick}>
              <Text>{this.state.clicked && this.state.selected}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
```

Comment: Are `selected` and `clicked` part of your state? They don't look like they are from your snippet. Mind sharing the entire component?

Comment: Where's the state `randomStatus.demand`?

Comment: sorry guys, that was typos! Might bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you meant to say `randomItem` instead of `randomStatus` in handleClick().

Try changing handleClick() like so:

```
    handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      clicked: true,
      selected:
        prev.randomItem[Math.floor(Math.random() * prev.randomItem.length) + 0]
    }));
  };
```

Also, I think your state has a typo as well. It should be:

```
    state = {
    randomItem: ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
    selected: null,
    clicked: false
  };
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Now, another question. Is it possible to use the same handleClick to have two different outputs? e.g one text might render "One" and another Text might render "Four" Or will I need to modify or have a separate script to achieve that

Comment: Add selected1 and selected2 to state.